# How to Temporarily Disable Eureka Server support in Ribbon and FeignClient

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-feign, netflix-ribbon

I have two micro-services(***car-management-service*** & ***rent-management-service***), in ***rent-management-service*** i'm calling ***car-management-service*** through Ribbon& FeignClient with the help of Eureka Discovery Server. And it's working perfectly.

I have started three instances of ***car-management-service*** running on port (8100,8101,8102), and Eureka provide these three instances perfectly one after the other.

Now I want to try is it possible to limit this to call only two of these instances by disabling (Temporary- just to Test is it possible) Eureka and providing direct urls of the ***car-management-service*** instances while still keeping Ribbon & FeignClient.

Portion of the `application.yml` of ***rent-management-service***

```yaml
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8761/eureka}
car-management-service:
  ribbon:
    eureka:
      enabled: false
    listOfServers: localhost:8100, localhost:8101
    #listOfServers: localhost:8100, localhost:8101, localhost:8102
    ServerListRefreshInterval: 1000
```

Portion of the `application.yml` of ***car-management-service***

```yaml
server:
  port: 8100
eureka:
  client:
    enabled: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8761/eureka}
```

Even though I have disabled Eureka in ***rent-management-service*** for discover ***car-management-service*** instances and hardcoded two of the three running ***car-management-service*** instances, ***rent-management-service*** still picks up all the three instances.

Why is it happening? Is there wrong with application.yml configuration or ***rent-management-service*** still picks up all the three ***car-management-service*** instances because they have the Eureka server dependency in pom.xml?

Comment: In rent-managment-service try use-> ribbon.eureka.enabled: false instead car-management-service.ribbon.eureka.enabled: false

Comment: @DavidAraujo if I do so, doesn't it  disable the use of Eureka Service support in entire rent-managment-service? Including all the other services (except ***car-management-service***) used in rent-service with the help of Feign&Ribbon? I want to limit/hardcode two instances only for the ***car-management-service***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand right you want 3rd instance from your car-management-service not to get traffic from discovery service. isn't it? you run 3 instances but you want to keep one away from eureka? 
you can do this.
run 2 instances from car-management-service and in 3rd instance add bellow property

```java
eureka:
  client:
    fetch-registry: false
    register-with-eureka: false
```

in this case that 3rd service will not register with eureka.

Comment: Thank you @krishantha-dinesh, that solves the question between the ***car-management-service & rent-management-service*** but doing so third instance becomes obsolete, right? no other services also can't use the third instance of ***car-management-service***. I seeking a way to disable eureka's help and hardcode 2 instances of  ***car-management-service*** used with ***rent-management-service***, but all three instance will still be used by services other than the ***rent-management-service***.